# Ubuntu 14.04 Second Monitor Not Detected through DVI, but detected through VGA cable

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I used to connect a 24" monitor to my laptop, equipped with GeForce410M, through HDMI cable. It sometimes had problems with detecting the monitor, but after a restart it managed to detect. Today the restarting did not function any more. I was using proprietary drivers and to resolve the problem switched to other drivers but it didn't bring anything. Then I found a VGA cable and connected the monitor through it. The monitor was surprisingly detected... What may be the reason of this issue? How can I fix it?